# Java synchronized function is producing different output on Mac vs Windows

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to work through a book learning Java. The code below is producing different output on a Mac versus a Windows PC. I have a Macbook M2 air using `OpenJDK 21.0.2` which is the latest for the Mac I believe and on the windows 11 PC, I am using `openjdk 22 2024-03-19`  The output that I am supposed to be getting is correct on the Windows but on the Mac I am getting the following:

```
[Hello]
[World]
[Synchronized]
```

I'm not sure why this happening since a `synchronized` block should theoretically produce the same output across all platforms?

```
 class Callme { 
    void call(String msg) { 
        System.out.print("[" + msg); 
        
        try { 
           Thread.sleep(1000); 
        } catch (InterruptedException e) 
        { 
            System.out.println("Interrupted"); 
        } 
        System.out.println("]"); }  
}

 class Caller implements Runnable {
        String msg;
        Callme target;
        Thread t;
    
        public Caller(Callme targ, String s) {
            target = targ;
            msg = s;
            t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();
        }
    
        // synchronize calls to call()
        public void run() {
            synchronized (target) { // synchronized block
                target.call(msg);
            }
        }
    }

class Synch1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Callme target = new Callme();
        Caller ob1 = new Caller(target, "Hello");
        Caller ob2 = new Caller(target, "Synchronized");
        Caller ob3 = new Caller(target, "World");
        // wait for threads to end
        try {
            ob1.t.join();
            ob2.t.join();
            ob3.t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to run this code on both a MAC laptop and a Windows 11 PC and it runs fine on the windows computer but it is producing output that is out of order on the MAC Laptop. I'm not sure why this is happening or how to fix this.

**Update**
I reran the script on my windows 11 PC and its doing the same thing as the MAC. However the first time I ran it, it produced the correct output on the Windows.

Comment: I'm guessing the expected output is "Hello" then "synchronized" then "world". If so, then it doesn't produce expect results since threads run concurrently and do not execute in order.

Comment: Yes it supposed to be in the order you specified.  According to the book, it should show that output. As you mention threads do not execute in order.

Comment: I think the book meant it as an example run, not necessary as such that all runs will produce such output. The workings of threads are different from traditional singe thread programs and they execute at the same time for a multitude of efficiency reasons, such that the program could produce any output of the three as long as they scheduled that way

Comment: The `And:` lines I added, and you removed, were to make your code more readable. Combining three separate classes in one block is confusing.

Comment: Does the book you're reading claim you should *always* see the same output as the example output? Or is there a disclaimer somewhere that says you may see slightly different output? If the former, and that code is straight from the book, then the book is simply wrong.

Comment: @Slaw Yeah it mentions the output of the program is as follows which I took for that it should match with the output. But dealing with threads, it can run differently especially it being OS dependent as well as the compiler version.

Comment: I am using `Java: The Complete Reference, Ninth Edition` to learn this stuff from in case you guys are wondering.

Comment: In that case, I think the book is more misleading/unclear than outright wrong. My guess is that the author(s) simply forgot to clarify you may see the output in a different order or did make that clarification but earlier in the chapter or even a previous chapter (e.g., a general disclaimer that the order of execution in multithreaded code is unpredictable).

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't pass `this` to a new thread from within a constructor. You lose some guarantees if you do, and in particular you may see the default, un-initialized values for `final` fields, or even partial views of objects; it's a data race. I don't have a reference handy just now, but I'm sure there are resources via online searches for more details.

Answer (score 3):

### Thread scheduling and execution is arbitrary, unpredictable

You cannot predict which thread will be scheduled for how long in what order.

You apparently think in terms of starting your ob1, ob2, ob3 threads in that order. But actually, they need not *execute* in that order. You launch a thread in the constructor of each. It is entirely possible that thread in `ob2` might get scheduled sooner that the thread in `ob1`, or that the thread in `ob3` might get more execution time that the other two. So your three threads, and their three outputs, might happen in any order.

You commented:

> Is there a way you can guarantee order or no?

If you want three tasks to execute in sequence, do *not* run them in separate threads. Run them in the same single thread!

Furthermore, be aware that your three launched threads could all finish running before the original thread executes your first `join` call in line `ob1.t.join();`. The three successive calls to `ob….t.join` suggest you might naïvely be thinking that the three spawned threads will still be running. They *may* still be running. Or, any or all of the three threads may have finished before the `join` calls execute. Again, threads’ scheduling and execution vary unpredictably, controlled by the host operating system’s thread scheduler whose behavior may change based on changing runtime conditions.

### `ExecutorService`

In modern Java, we rarely address the `Thread` class directly. The Executors framework was added to Java 5 to relieve us Java programmers of the troublesome burden of managing threads. In most situations, we can use executor service to execute our tasks defined as `Runnable`/`Callable` objects.

Regarding your comment about running three tasks in a particular sequence, I suggested above to use an executor service backed by a single thread. Here is a little example.

```java
// Be aware that output to System.out does *not* necessarily appear in chronological order when called across threads. Use a thread-safe log instead.
SequencedCollection < String > log = new CopyOnWriteArrayList <>( );
log.add( "INFO - Demo start. " + Instant.now( ) );
SequencedCollection < Runnable > tasks =
        List.of(
                new Runnable( )
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run ( )
                    {
                        log.add( "alpha " + Instant.now( ) ) ;
                    }
                } ,
                new Runnable( )
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run ( )
                    {
                        log.add( "beta " + Instant.now( ) ) ;
                    }
                } ,
                new Runnable( )
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run ( )
                    {
                        log.add( "gamma " + Instant.now( ) ) ;
                    }
                }
        );
try (
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor( ) ;
)
{
    tasks.forEach( executorService :: submit );
}
// Flow-of-control blocks here until all submitted tasks finish, or 24 hours, whichever comes first.
log.add( "INFO - Demo done. " + Instant.now( ) );
log.forEach( System.out :: println );
```

Notice above that in recent versions of Java an [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) is [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html). So we can use try-with-resources syntax.

We can shorten those `new Runnable` lines by using lambdas.

```java
SequencedCollection < Runnable > tasks =
        List.of(
                ( ) -> log.add( "alpha " + Instant.now( ) ) ,
                ( ) -> log.add( "beta " + Instant.now( ) ) ,
                ( ) -> log.add( "gamma " + Instant.now( ) )
        );
```

Example output:

```
INFO - Demo start. 2024-03-23T04:01:40.663178Z
alpha 2024-03-23T04:01:40.669185Z
beta 2024-03-23T04:01:40.669387Z
gamma 2024-03-23T04:01:40.669442Z
INFO - Demo done. 2024-03-23T04:01:40.669578Z
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way you can guarantee order or no?

Comment: two cents: even if spawned threads were scheduled "properly", native synchronization is not guaranteed to be fair.

Comment: @legendary91 by not using threads. There is a pretty fundamental mismatch between 'i need job A to run first and finish, then job B to run and finish, then job C to run and finish, in that exact order', and 'I want to use threads'. That's rather similar to saying: "I want a corner." followed by: "But, with a circle".

Comment: Re, "be aware that your three launched threads could all finish running before the original thread executes your first join call." That seems like a strange thing to say. You're more or less warning that the main thread might not have to wait for the other threads to finish. Well, OK. So, is there a problem? What if it _doesn't_ have to wait. Why should the OP "be aware" of that?

Comment: @SolomonSlow The three successive calls to `ob….t.join` suggest that a naïve programmer might write such code thinking that the three spawned threads are still running. They may in fact have all finished before any of the `join` calls execute. I added some more prose to hopefully make that point clearly.

Answer (score -1):

synchronized is a unfair lock,you can run agian on your mac or windows.it will show diffrent answers .all permutations will be possible.

Comment: The fairness or unfairness of the lock has no bearing on which thread will reach it first.